# Storing science data

Tags: database, bigdata

Each sensor has resolution of 10 bits and there are 500 measurements per second. Also, we are storing timestamp of first measurement for each detection (let's say we leave 32 bits for this).

500 measurments * 10 bits + 32 bits = 5032 bits per detection

Lets assume that each detection lasts 1 sec and that there are 500 detections per hour per sensor. That leaves us with about 307KB per hour per sensor of data. Let's say that there are 10 sensors and we have 25,7GB of data per year (without taking in account that we should also store identifiers for each sensor).

Now, ~26GB isn't much and I guess that simple MySQL database could hold it. Problem is that later data will be processed using some heavy algorithms and data from different sensors will constantly be compared one to another.

Example of querys that could be made:

- "get all detections of sensor3 and sensor4 if difference between two timestamps is less than 0.5s" (ie. matching detections)
- "get all detections on 1st of March 2014 if peak in measurements is greater than 900"
- "compare detection #3 from sensor1 and detection #7 from sensor7" (ie. tells if detections match based on measurement data, not timestamp)

Each detection is essentially a curve.

Question is what solution to pick for database. Are relational databases good enough for this? If yes, which one allows listed operations? If no, is no-sql way to go and why?

**TL;DR:**

How to store large number of very similar scientific data? We are talking about 21900000000 measurements yearly, divided into 4380000 observations for each of 10 sensors. It must be possible to do complex calculation and comparison of observations later. Also, depending on solution, how to organize data?

Comment: I do not recommend a traditional relation database for this purpose; it can handle it but it will get too expensive probably. Use some type of database that can handle such volume of streaming data. You might even want to look into your own binary format for the primary storage. Give the linux server sufficient memory and it should all fit into memory.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into hdf5. It is really good at storing array-like data; only thing is last time I was using it, it wasn't very robust during development; if my code crashed with an open connection, it would often corrupt my whole dataset. I believe the newest version addresses this issue though.

Comment: Do you mind answering last question? How would you organize data in this case using hdf5?

Comment: I think you have to have 2 database: one for realtime storing (transactional processing), second for processing (analytical processing). First database have to fast for storing (don't use a lot of indexes). Data from first database will be periodically transferred to second database. Second database should have many indexes or/and aggregates to quickly respond to queries.

Comment: I would say the straightforward organization of such data would be to create one extensible array for each sensor, where the atom (datatype/row descriptor) would be a timestamp object plus an array of 500 16 bits ints. The amount of data stored per second is rather trivial; and hdf5 makes it a breeze to add suitable compression to it as well. I don't know what language you work in, but pytables is a good place to start exploring hdf5.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: I'm working in Java. So you are suggesting storing each observation as one row which contains timestamp data, sensor ID and array with 500 measurements? I guess that ~50M rows per years won't slow down hdf5?

Comment: `often corrupt my whole dataset` - if it still is in such condition, it would be a good idea to have a some additional databases to keep backups of the data and to allow the crashing-highperf one to be restored, just in case.. Those backup databases can freely use different storage engines, data compression, etc. They can also be used by as datasources for all the non-intensive processes (like users and scientists browsing through the data), while the critical one would be reserved for the actual online processing.

Comment: @Dario; yeah, that's the idea. However, you may want to store the 500 measurements in a separate table. This allows you to specify chunked storage, which may be desirable; for instance if you want to compare a slice of ten columns out of those 500 for a large N of rows, you don't need to read 500xN from disk, but only ~10xN. Afaik hdf5 will be fine as long as you still have disk space. It manages internal storage by some chunk tree based method, so appending/inserting new data is not dependent on the dataset as a whole, performance wise.

Comment: @quet: I think the most important thing is to keep your measurement code simple, and build in a clean way to exit it while properly closing the db connection (ie, don't just kill the process). Processes that don't have a write connection are not a liability.

See this discussion: https://www.mail-archive.com/hdf-forum@hdfgroup.org/msg03614.html

The internal redundancy features to guard against corruption were planned for 1.10, which isn't out yet. So its still good to be aware of these issues.